# LVM hangs while trying to create my root device node

Tags: lvm

Followup to [How can I check for bad blocks on an LVM physical volume?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92076/how-can-i-check-for-bad-blocks-on-an-lvm-physical-volume)

The title mostly sums it up. Basically, I have a box partitioned with a regular `/boot` partition and then an LVM physical volume filling up the rest of the drive. In LVM I have one volume group with a root partition, a `/home` partition, and a swap partition.

When LVM creates the device nodes in `/dev/mapper`, it creates the swap and home partitions fine. However, it usually hangs while trying to create the root device node. This happens from a live CD (`pvscan; vgscan; vgchange -ay` is what I used, IIRC) and also from the initial ramdisk, preventing the box from booting. I've also tried from the initrd recovery shell (`lvm pvscan; lvm vgscan; lvm vgchange -ay` is what I used, IIRC), which also fails in the same way.

Sometimes, `vgchange -ay` actually creates the root device node (after a really long delay) but never exits, leaving me to kill it manually. When this happens I try to mount the device, but it always hangs indefinitely. Note that while both of those commands are running, the console spits out a bunch of messages about failed command "READ DMA" or something.

I've run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` a couple times. Each time it gives a fair amount of errors about bad blocks (IIRC), but ultimately says that the drive is in good condition.

I've put up [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0P8usF8q) of `dmesg` on the affected machine. The logs come from booting an Arch Linux live cd, then running `pvscan; vgscan; vgchange -ay`. `vgchange -ay` hung forever this time, and I eventually killed it. Here's the end of `dmesg`, for posterity (and so I [don't use a pastebin[2](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/policy-on-pastebins-for-additional-info)):

```
[   46.332920] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[   58.503496] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[167992.304649] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[167992.304660] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[168092.874016] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[168163.318923] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[168459.839738] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[168472.010337] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[168614.642035] bio: create slab <bio-2> at 2
[168630.045526] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[168630.045649] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x65
[168630.045710] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[168630.045787] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:10:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 4096 in
         res 51/40:08:00:10:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[168630.046006] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[168630.046071] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[168630.066286] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[168630.079493] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/66
[168630.079514] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[168630.079517] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168630.079520] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[168630.079523] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168630.079525] Sense Key : 0x3 [current] [descriptor]
[168630.079530] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[168630.079532]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[168630.079544]         06 10 10 00 
[168630.079549] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168630.079551] ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4
[168630.079554] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[168630.079556] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 06 10 10 00 00 00 08 00
[168630.079567] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 101715968
[168630.079665] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0
[168630.079775] ata1: EH complete
[168634.564062] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[168634.564165] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x64
[168634.564225] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[168634.564301] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:80:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 4096 in
         res 51/10:00:83:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 Emask 0x81 (invalid argument)
[168634.564527] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[168634.564592] ata1.00: error: { IDNF }
[168634.584336] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[168634.597559] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/66
[168634.597578] ata1: EH complete
[168639.087353] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[168639.087462] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x64
[168639.087521] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[168639.087596] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:80:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 4096 in
         res 51/10:00:83:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 Emask 0x81 (invalid argument)
[168639.087822] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[168639.087886] ata1.00: error: { IDNF }
[168639.105791] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[168639.118999] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/66
[168639.119017] ata1: EH complete
[168645.896986] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[168645.897095] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x64
[168645.897155] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[168645.900373] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:80:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 4096 in
         res 51/40:00:83:0f:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[168645.906936] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[168645.910263] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[168645.931315] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[168645.944504] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/66
[168645.944525] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[168645.944529] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168645.944531] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[168645.944534] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168645.944537] Sense Key : 0x3 [current] [descriptor]
[168645.944541] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[168645.944543]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[168645.944554]         06 10 0f 83 
[168645.944559] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168645.944561] ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4
[168645.944564] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[168645.944566] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 06 10 0f 80 00 00 08 00
[168645.944578] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 101715843
[168645.947946] Buffer I/O error on device dm-2, logical block 10485744
[168645.951439] ata1: EH complete
[168650.445911] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[168650.449275] ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x65
[168650.452579] ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
[168650.455873] ata1.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:10:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 tag 0 dma 4096 in
         res 51/40:08:00:10:10/00:00:00:00:00/e6 Emask 0x9 (media error)
[168650.462537] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[168650.465714] ata1.00: error: { UNC }
[168650.486063] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[168650.499326] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/66
[168650.499344] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code
[168650.499348] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168650.499350] Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[168650.499353] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168650.499355] Sense Key : 0x3 [current] [descriptor]
[168650.499360] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[168650.499362]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[168650.499373]         06 10 10 00 
[168650.499378] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  
[168650.499380] ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x4
[168650.499383] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: 
[168650.499385] cdb[0]=0x28: 28 00 06 10 10 00 00 00 08 00
[168650.499396] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 101715968
[168650.502757] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0
[168650.506189] ata1: EH complete
[168798.816025] usb 9-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
```

This is just the end of the log, where the errors began, because I hit the post limit. To see the whole thing, look at the pastebin.

Apologies for not giving specific information, but I'm not in front of the affected box right now.

Answer (score 2):

From the extra info you provided, it sounds like you've got a bad drive (bad blocks). You can try and work around these issues if you'd like, but I'd seriously consider replacing the drive.

If you want to work around the issue, basically you're going to have to find the LVM physical extents that sit on top of the bad blocks, and add those physical extents to a logical volume that must not be used.

There is actually a fairly recent email chain on the linux-lvm mailing list on this subject (I'd read the whole chain, it contains a lot of info):

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2012-November/msg00033.html

---

On this specific message, it looks like someone created a python script to help with the task:

https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2012-November/msg00038.html

> Having helped people in such situations (where internet at least was
>   working), I've used the attached script to help find affected LVs and
>   files.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Identify partition, LV, file containing a sector 

# Copyright (C) 2010,2012 Stuart D. Gathman
# Shared under GNU Public License v2 or later
#   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#   (at your option) any later version.

#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#   GNU General Public License for more details.

#   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along
#   with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc.,
#   51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.

import sys
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

ID_LVM = 0x8e
ID_LINUX = 0x83
ID_EXT = 0x05
ID_RAID = 0xfd

def idtoname(id):
  if id == ID_LVM: return "Linux LVM"
  if id == ID_LINUX: return "Linux Filesystem"
  if id == ID_EXT: return "Extended Partition"
  if id == ID_RAID: return "Software RAID"
  return hex(id)

class Segment(object):
  __slots__ = ('pe1st','pelst','lvpath','le1st','lelst')
  def __init__(self,pe1st,pelst):
    self.pe1st = pe1st;
    self.pelst = pelst;
  def __str__(self):
    return "Seg:%d-%d:%s:%d-%d" % (
      self.pe1st,self.pelst,self.lvpath,self.le1st,self.lelst)

def cmdoutput(cmd):
  p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
  try:
    for ln in p.stdout:
      yield ln
  finally:
    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()

def icheck(fs,blk):
  "Return inum from block number, or 0 if free space."
  for ln in cmdoutput("debugfs -R 'icheck %d' '%s' 2>/dev/null"%(blk,fs)):
    b,i = ln.strip().split(None,1)
    if not b[0].isdigit(): continue
    if int(b) == blk:
      if i.startswith('<'):
    return 0
      return int(i)
  raise ValueError('%s: invalid block: %d'%(fs,blk))

def ncheck(fs,inum):
  "Return filename from inode number, or None if not linked."
  for ln in cmdoutput("debugfs -R 'ncheck %d' '%s' 2>/dev/null"%(inum,fs)):
    i,n = ln.strip().split(None,1)
    if not i[0].isdigit(): continue
    if int(i) == inum:
      return n
  return None

def blkid(fs):
  "Return dictionary of block device attributes"
  d = {}
  for ln in cmdoutput("blkid -o export '%s'"%fs):
    k,v = ln.strip().split('=',1)
    d[k] = v
  return d

def getpvmap(pv):
  pe_start = 192 * 2
  pe_size = None
  seg = None
  segs = []
  for ln in cmdoutput("pvdisplay --units k -m %s"%pv):
    a = ln.strip().split()
    if not a: continue
    if a[0] == 'Physical' and a[4].endswith(':'):
      pe1st = int(a[2])
      pelst = int(a[4][:-1])
      seg = Segment(pe1st,pelst)
    elif seg and a[0] == 'Logical':
      if a[1] == 'volume':
    seg.lvpath = a[2]
      elif a[1] == 'extents':
    seg.le1st = int(a[2])
    seg.lelst = int(a[4])
    segs.append(seg)
    elif a[0] == 'PE' and a[1] == 'Size':
      if a[2] == "(KByte)":
    pe_size = int(a[3]) * 2
      elif a[3] == 'KiB':
    pe_size = int(float(a[2])) * 2
  if segs:
    for ln in cmdoutput("pvs --units k -o+pe_start %s"%pv):
      a = ln.split()
      if a[0] == pv:
        lst = a[-1]
    if lst.lower().endswith('k'):
      pe_start = int(float(lst[:-1]))*2
      return pe_start,pe_size,segs
  return None

def findlv(pv,sect):
  res = getpvmap(pv)
  if not res: return None
  pe_start,pe_size,m = res
  if sect < pe_start:
    raise Exception("Bad sector in PV metadata area")
  pe = int((sect - pe_start)/pe_size)
  pebeg = pe * pe_size + pe_start
  peoff = sect - pebeg
  for s in m:
    if s.pe1st <= pe <= s.pelst:
      le = s.le1st + pe - s.pe1st
      return s.lvpath,le * pe_size + peoff

def getmdmap():
  with open('/proc/mdstat','rt') as fp:
    m = []
    for ln in fp:
      if ln.startswith('md'):
    a = ln.split(':')
    raid = a[0].strip()
    devs = []
    a = a[1].split()
    for d in a[2:]:
      devs.append(d.split('[')[0])
    m.append((raid,devs))
    return m

def parse_sfdisk(s):
  for ln in s:
    try:
      part,desc = ln.split(':')
      if part.startswith('/dev/'):
        d = {}
        for p in desc.split(','):
      name,val = p.split('=')
      name = name.strip()
      if name.lower() == 'id':
        d[name] = int(val,16)
      else:
        d[name] = int(val)
    yield part.strip(),d
    except ValueError:
      continue

def findpart(wd,lba):
  s = cmdoutput("sfdisk -d %s"%wd)
  parts = [ (part,d['start'],d['size'],d['Id']) for part,d in parse_sfdisk(s) ]
  for part,start,sz,Id in parts:
    if Id == ID_EXT: continue
    if start <= lba < start + sz:
      return part,lba - start,Id
  return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
  wd = sys.argv[1]
  lba = int(sys.argv[2])
  print wd,lba,"Whole Disk"
  res = findpart(wd,lba)
  if not res:
    print "LBA is outside any partition"
    sys.exit(1)
  part,sect,Id = res
  print part,sect,idtoname(Id)
  if Id == ID_LVM:
    bd,sect = findlv(part,sect)
    # FIXME: problems if LV is snapshot
  elif Id == ID_LINUX:
    bd = part
  else:
    if Id == ID_RAID:
      for md,devs in getmdmap():
    for dev in devs:
      if part == "/dev/"+dev:
        part = "/dev/"+md
        break
        else: continue
    break
    res = findlv(part,sect)
    if res:
      print "PV =",part
      bd,sect = res
    else:
      bd = part
  blksiz = 4096
  blk = int(sect * 512 / blksiz)
  p = blkid(bd)
  try:
    t = p['TYPE']
  except:
    print bd,p
    raise
  print "fs=%s block=%d %s"%(bd,blk,t)
  if t.startswith('ext'):
    inum = icheck(bd,blk)
    if inum:
      fn = ncheck(bd,inum)
      print "file=%s inum=%d"%(fn,inum)
    else:
      print "<free space>"
```